# Updating subtotal of items in repeater

Tags: c#, asp.net, repeater

I have repeater that used to display item name, price, input textbox used to enter amount and label used to show the price * amount for each item.
I can calculate the price * amount with JavaScript.
This is code (if you need it) I use to find the outcome

```
function setAmountOther(row) {

    var firstUnderscore = row.indexOf("_");
    var lastUnderscore = row.lastIndexOf("_");

    var totalOther = 0;

    var rowID = row.substring(firstUnderscore, lastUnderscore + 1); // get the control id _ctlXX_ (where XX is row number)

    var rowAmont = Number($('#rptOtherProducts' + rowID + 'txtProductQuantityOther').val()); // get the amount of the product

    var rowPrice = Number($('#rptOtherProducts' + rowID + 'lblProductsPriceOther').text()); // get the price of the product

    totalForRow = rowAmont * rowPrice; // get total for row

    totalOther += totalForRow; // get total for order

    $('#rptOtherProducts' + rowID + 'lblProductTotalOther').html(totalForRow);  // set the total price of the item


}
```

The question is how I can add all the outcomes of each items to a label that show the subtotal of the items, and how I can update it if someone change the amount of item?
For example: if I enter 2 and price of item is 20 the outcome is 40, and subtotal is 40, but is I enter 1 the outcome is 20, but the subtotal remains 40.

Any solution in JavaScript,asp.net with C#, or any other idea will be very helpful.
(I searched but did not find anything useful, maybe I search the wrong keywords)

If you need anything else, please let me know.

Thanks

EDIT:
Source code in the repeater:

```
<ItemTemplate>
                            <div class="divProductsMain" style="margin: 0 -116px 0 0">
                                <div class="divProdcutTotal">
                                    <label id="lblProductTotalOther" runat="server">
                                        0</label>&nbsp;&#8362;
                                </div>
                                <div class="divProductsQuantity">
                                    <input type="text" id="txtProductQuantityOther" runat="server" class="txtProductQuantity"
                                        maxlength="3" onkeyup="setAmountOther(this.id)" />
                                </div>
                                <div class="divProductsPrice">
                                    <asp:Label ID="lblProductsPriceOther" runat="server"><%#Eval("Price", "{0:0.00}")%></asp:Label>&nbsp;&#8362;
                                </div>
                                <div class="divProductDescription">
                                    <asp:Label ID="lblProductDescriptionOther" runat="server"><%#Eval("Name")%></asp:Label>
                                </div>
                                <div class="divComputerCode">
                                    <asp:Label ID="lblComputerCodeOther" runat="server"><%#Eval("ComputerCode")%></asp:Label>
                                </div>
                            </div>
                        </ItemTemplate>
```

If you need anything else please tell me.

Answer (score 0):

Call the calculation Function on 
`OnKeyUp`(event) of the textboxes in which you are accepting the amount and price

Comment: I doing it per items, I using onkeyup="setAmount(this.id)" where "this.id" send me the control id, that I using the get the amount and price like on the code I put above (row get the this.id value).
My problem is the add all the items' cost and write it on label.
If I have 2 items, the first cost 10 and I have 2 of it the outcome of it is 20, and second cost 20 and I have 2 of it, the outcome of it is 40, and the subtotal of the 2 items is 60, but if I change the amount of the first item to 1 it outcome change to 10, but the subtotal of both item do not change, I want to change to subtotal too

Comment: can you post your repeater markup how you have placed the controls,so that i can give you accurate answer

Comment: I found some kind of solution, I call function that sum all row each time I enter or change number.